# Passing an enum as an annotation parameter and getting list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a custom attribute, that will be used to define that the property is used in a DropDownList. So the code of attribute is this:

```
public class DropDownList : Attribute
{
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public DropDownList(Type type)
    {
        this.EnumType = type;
    }
}
```

I can't pass the enum as paramater, I only could do this passing the type of enum, like this:

```
class TestViewModel
{
    [DropDownList(typeof(MyEnums.EnumTest)]
    public int MyProp {get; set;}
}
```

I have a HTML extension, that needs to work like this:

```
public HtmlString AddSelectFor<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    var attribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyProj.Attributes.DropDownList), false).FirstOrDefault() as MyProj.Attributes.DropDownList;

    // HERE i need to get the list of enum itens
    var items = Enum.GetValues(attribute.EnumType);
    return HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, list);
}
```

The problem is that I don't have the enum, I have only the type, because it needs to be generic. So I can't do the cast to create the list needed as parameter for "HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor".

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question. `Enum.GetValues` takes a `Type`, which you have, so it will return the items - what is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it takes. But to get a list from it, i have to Cast it before. Like this: var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToList(); The problem is, i just have the type of Enum, so, how i'll do the cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it, only casting with "Enum", and then, selecting a SelectListItem to pass to DropDownList:

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(attribute.EnumType).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem(){
                    Text = x.ToString(),
                    Value = Convert.ToInt32(x).ToString()
                });
```

thanks.

Comment: Note the `Value` property should also be `Value = x.ToString(),` - The `DefaultModelBinder` uses the `.ToString()` value when binding to an enum on post back